# Firefox won't display hidden div when shown using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, vimeo, getcomputedstyle

I'm building a website that has a floating vimeo iframe in the center. By default, the vimeo container is set to "display:none;". Once the play button is clicked, I use jQuery to fade the iframe in.

It works in all browsers except for Firefox. I'm getting this error:

```
s.getComputedStyle(...) is null
```

Here's the code I'm using to fade in the div that contains the iframe:

```
$('a.playbutton').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#cover-content').hide();
        $('.vimeo-container').css("display","table").fadeIn(animSpeed);
        player.api('play');
    });
```

I've tried using "display:block" as well as "display:table" and neither of them are working in Firefox.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or know what's causing it?

Comment: Why are you using `display:block` and `fadeIn()` both. Use one

Comment: instead of `display`, try `visibility` property

Comment: Related : **[getComputedStyle(..) is null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22484768/3639582)**

Comment: @Shaunak D - I've tried just using fadeIn() and it didn't work either. I tried using the three rules in that other question (overflow, opacity, height), but that also didn't work.

Comment: @Amit Soni - I tried using visibility:hidden in my CSS and changing it to visibility:visible in jQuery, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $('.vimeo-container').fadeIn(animSpeed);
```

instead of this

```
$('.vimeo-container').css("display","table").fadeIn(animSpeed);
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but the iframe still isn't fading in.

Comment: Remove "display:none;" from  the vimeo container. When you load the page, at that time, make it invisible by using fadeOut method.